# How do I use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke properly?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, dispatcher

I have searched almost everywhere on the internet, and I have googled so many times and found so many results, but I still can't find the solution to my problem.

I am busy converting an old `WinForms` application to a new WPF application but I am having trouble with some of the commands. In the Winforms application they use `Control.BeginInvoke()` and store this in an IAsyncResult object. I have read that the `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` is the `WPF` equivalent to the `Control.BeginInvoke()` for `WinForms` but I get this error when I use

> Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(): "Cannot implicitly convert type
>     'System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation' to 'System.IAsyncResult'. 
>     An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)".

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the code that I am trying to convert. This is the original `WinForms` code. I am able to convert everything except the BeginInvoke part.

```
    private eSkan.api.TeSkanAPI feSkanAPI = null;

    private void MessageFilter_AddRemove_Invoked(bool AddFilter, IMessageFilter Filter)
    {
        if (AddFilter){ Application.AddMessageFilter(Filter); }
        else { Application.RemoveMessageFilter(Filter); }
    }

    private void MessageFilter_AddRemove(bool AddFilter, IMessageFilter Filter)
    {
        {
            IAsyncResult sr = BeginInvoke((ESKAN_ADD_REMOVE_MESSAGEFILTER)MessageFilter_AddRemove_Invoked,
                                          AddFilter, Filter);
            sr.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(2000);
        }
    }
```

Below is my code that I have converted so far including the BeginInvoke part that I am struggling with.

```
    private void MessageFilter_AddRemove_Invoked(bool addFilter, System.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter filter)
    {
        if (addFilter) 
        { 
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.AddMessageFilter(filter); 
        }
        else 
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.Application.RemoveMessageFilter(filter); 
        }
    }

    private void MessageFilter_AddRemove(bool addFilter, System.Windows.Forms.IMessageFilter filter)
    {
        {
            IAsyncResult sr = System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((ESKAN_ADD_REMOVE_MESSAGEFILTER)MessageFilter_AddRemove_Invoked, addFilter, filter);
            sr.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(2000);
        }
    }
```

If there are any other mistakes then please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code that you're trying to convert?  It seems that you're using the return value of `Control.BeginInvoke` in the original but, without seeing how, it's hard to comment on the appropriate change.

Comment: Michael's answer is good - but it's also worth noting that the line `sr.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(2000)` just pauses the current thread for 2 seconds, and would appear to be redundant (at least, I would *hope* it's redundant...).  If you remove that line, you don't need the return value at all (just the callback).

Comment: Yes Michael's answer is good but I am still having trouble with one small part. I need to use a custom API for the callback. That is the part where they assign the BeginInvoke() to the the IAsyncResult object. I have tried a few ways to get the code right so that it can perform it's function but I am struggling to get it right.

Answer (score 4):

That's because [`Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591206.aspx), though it may be the equivalent logical operation, doesn't return an `IAsyncResult`, it returns a [`DispatcherOperation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcheroperation.aspx). Have a look at [this blog post](http://tech.pro/tutorial/800/working-with-the-wpf-dispatcher) and you'll see a good example on how the `Dispatcher` works. I have copied the relevant code example into here to ensure it exists later.

```
public Window1()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  CheckBox myCheckBox = new CheckBox();
  myCheckBox.Content = "A Checkbox";

  System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(
    new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
      delegate()
      {
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation
          dispatcherOp = myCheckBox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
          System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
          new Action(
            delegate()
            {
              myCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
            }
        ));

        dispatcherOp.Completed += new EventHandler(dispatcherOp_Completed);
      }
  ));

  thread.Start();
}

void dispatcherOp_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Console.WriteLine("The checkbox has finished being updated!");
}
```

Take note to this line:

```
dispatcherOp.Completed += new EventHandler(dispatcherOp_Completed);
```

that's how you're going to know when it's completed - it's going to call back to you via that event.

Comment: I would just like help with one more thing. That is that I need to pass two different variables to a function that I am calling. Please see my code above if unclear.